# throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, web

I'm trying to run a node.js app locally,

I installed all the dependencies by

```
npm install
```

I have mongodb running in a separate console tab, showing something like

```
[~/apps/Mi aguila]$ sudo mongod                                                                                                                        rvm:ruby-2.1.1 
mongod --help for help and startup options
2014-07-10T10:40:16.096-0500 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7067 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=localhost
2014-07-10T10:40:16.097-0500 [initandlisten] 
2014-07-10T10:40:16.097-0500 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2014-07-10T10:40:16.097-0500 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.3
2014-07-10T10:40:16.097-0500 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2014-07-10T10:40:16.097-0500 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin minimavericks.local 13.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.2.0: Thu Apr 17 23:03:13 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.100.    13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-07-10T10:40:16.097-0500 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-07-10T10:40:16.097-0500 [initandlisten] options: {}
2014-07-10T10:40:16.099-0500 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2014-07-10T10:40:16.100-0500 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2014-07-10T10:40:16.133-0500 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/db/local.ns, filling with zeroes...
2014-07-10T10:40:16.133-0500 [FileAllocator] creating directory /data/db/_tmp
2014-07-10T10:40:16.203-0500 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db/local.ns, size: 16MB,  took 0.068 secs
2014-07-10T10:40:16.271-0500 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/db/local.0, filling with zeroes...
2014-07-10T10:40:16.383-0500 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db/local.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.111 secs
2014-07-10T10:40:16.449-0500 [initandlisten] build index on: local.startup_log properties: { v: 1, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "local.startup_log" }
2014-07-10T10:40:16.455-0500 [initandlisten]     added index to empty collection
2014-07-10T10:40:16.458-0500 [initandlisten] command local.$cmd command: create { create: "startup_log", size: 10485760, capped: true } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0     numYields:0  reslen:37 323ms
2014-07-10T10:40:16.466-0500 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2014-07-10T10:41:16.144-0500 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:9 virt:2635
2014-07-10T10:41:16.144-0500 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):160
2014-07-10T10:41:16.144-0500 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
2014-07-10T10:46:16.240-0500 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:5 virt:2635
2014-07-10T10:46:16.240-0500 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):160
2014-07-10T10:46:16.240-0500 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
```

And

When I run the app by

```
node app.js
```

And, I'm getting this error

```
rvm:ruby-2.1.1 
Config : dev

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1023:19)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at net.js:1146:9
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Comment: What is your script trying to listen on? Is that address/port already being used by another process?

Comment: You have to be su to listen to port 80...

Comment: It's trying to listen on 4430, I tried changing it to 80, 8080, 3000 and 2000 without success.

Comment: Also, The only port that is being used is port=27017 , used by MongoDB

Comment: How did you manage to solve this @StellaMiranda ?